# Display User Data from Local Storage in Profile

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm just starting my first Ionic app and am a little confused. I'm using a rails API to login a user and then I would like to display user information on the Ionic app (Name, Email, etc...).

I can't seem to pull in the user's email and name on my root page. Below is my code and I apologize for asking such a beginner level question.

**services.js**

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('User', function($resource) {
  return $resource("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/:id.json");
})

.factory('UserSession', function($resource) {
  return $resource("http://localhost:3000/login.json");
})
```

**controller.js**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, User) {
  $scope.user = User.get(localStorage['userId']);
})

.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $location, UserSession, $ionicPopup, $rootScope) {
  $scope.data = {};

  $scope.login = function() {
    var user_session = new UserSession({ user: $scope.data });
    user_session.$save(
      function(data){
        window.localStorage['userId'] = data.id;
        window.localStorage['userName'] = data.name;
        window.localStorage['userEmail'] = data.email;
        window.localStorage['userZip'] = data.zip;
        window.localStorage['userBalance'] = data.account_balance;
        $location.path('/tab/dash');
      },
      function(err){
        var error = err["data"]["error"]
        var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
          title: 'An error occured',
          template: error
        });
      }
    );
  }
});
```

**tab-dash.html**

```
<ion-view title="Overview">
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <h2>Name: {{user.name}}</h2>
    <p>Email: {{user.email}}</p>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

As you can see from the screenshot below the name and email values aren't showing in my view.

[image]

Here is also a screenshot of the values saved in my localStorage.

[image]

Comment: "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/:id.json" what does .json do here ? !!!!

Comment: @ZeRubeus I removed the .json and that didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: why you are using new with the service `UserSession` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess problem can be in this line

`$scope.user = User.get(localStorage['userId']);`

Try to change it to `$scope.user = User.get({id: localStorage['userId']});`

And check what do you receive in `$scope.user` variable. It can be promise and you will need to adjust nesting.

**Answer**

I updated the above code in my controller.js and also had a nesting issue in my views like you had mentioned.

In my views instead of `{{user.name}}` I needed to use `{{user.user.name}}`

Comment: thanks for the quick solution, I updated your answer with my solution based on your help!